# Lists in lists to sets inside sets - Python 3

Tags: python, set

In my code my result is a list, in which the items are lists. However, I am supposed to return the result as sets inside sets.

I return:

```
[['Anna', 'John']]
```

instead of

```
{('Anna', 'John')}.
```

I tried to change my result with:

```
result = set(frozenset(i) for i in result)
```

but this returns

```
{frozenset({'Anna', 'John'})} instead of {('Anna', 'John')}
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: `{('Anna', 'John')}` is a `set` that contains a `tuple`.

Comment: It is impossible to have a set inside a set. A set may only contain hashable types, which `set` is not. (thus the frozenset).

Comment: Thank you both very much! I managed to fix it. Excuse my ignorance and stupidity.